# numpy fft amplitude is not what excepted

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft

I have a following code just to get "right answers" from numpy fft.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = np.pi/2
Fs = 140
t = np.arange(0,n,1/Fs)

f1, f2, f3 = (20,45,60)
a1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t)
a2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f2*t)
a3 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f3*t)
y = a1+a2+a3

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.xlim(0,n)
plt.ylim(y.min()-0.2,y.max()+0.5)
plt.plot(t,y)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
N = len(t)
X = np.fft.fft(y)
freq = (Fs/2)*np.linspace(0,1,N//2)
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(X[:len(freq)])*2/N)
plt.show()
```

It produces this
[image]

Why fft amplitudes are not one for each frequency?
Help appreciated.

Comment: looks good to me ... are you asking why the freq domain plot is not showing tighter spikes on each of your 3 freqs ?

Comment: Shouldn't the spikes hight be 1? And also, they could be tighter.

Comment: If your fft frequencies are exactly your signal frequencies then you will get spikes at those frequencies.  If they are not, then you get what’s called spectral leakage.

Comment: The leakage is a function of the *duration* of the signal (not the frequency sampling per se). If you use a much longer signal, eg `n = np.pi*16`, you'll dramatically reduce the width of the spikes. As for the amplitudes... I think this is a result of harmonics, but I'm much less sure about that bit. Certainly if you vary the amplitudes, the relative amplitudes change too. BTW, since your code is fine, you might want to ask this Q on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/